# Update React Native slider on initial load without affecting animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a React Native checkbox/switch component (similar to a generic iOS switch).

The animation and functionality is working as required, but I'm having an issue with the initial view state.

When rendering the component, it's set in the "off" state initially. I can set an explicit `left` value to resolve this (e.g setting a dynamic `left` value based on the state of `checked`), but that will remove the `Animated` effect that's applied when the checkbox is changed.

Is there a way to update the checkbox with an initial state (true/false) without affecting the animation?

The component is below. It received two props presently (`checked` = a bool, `handleChange` = function to change the status of checked from the parent component).

```
const CheckboxToggle = ({ checked, handleChange }) => {
  const xAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const startThumbAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(xAnimation, {
      toValue: checked ? 0 : 50,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const animatedThumbStyles = {
    transform: [
      {
        translateX: xAnimation,
      }
    ]
  }

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        handleChange();
        startThumbAnimation();
      }}
    >
      <View>
        <Track />
        <AnimatedThumb
          checked={checked}
          style={animatedThumbStyles}
        >
          {
            checked
            ? <CheckboxIconTrue source={ic_switch_on} />
            : <CheckboxIconFalse source={ic_switch_off} />
          }
        </AnimatedThumb>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}


export default CheckboxToggle;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting deafult Animated.value conditionally?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- do you have any linkable examples of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this way:

```
const CheckboxToggle = ({ defaultCheck, checked, handleChange }) => {
  //using defaultCheck to conditionally set the value.
  const xAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(defaultCheck ? 50 : 0)).current;

  const startThumbAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(xAnimation, {
      toValue: checked ? 0 : 50,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const animatedThumbStyles = {
    transform: [
      {
        translateX: xAnimation,
      }
    ]
  }

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        handleChange();
        startThumbAnimation();
      }}
    >
      <View>
        <Track />
        <AnimatedThumb
          checked={checked}
          style={animatedThumbStyles}
        >
          {
            checked
            ? <CheckboxIconTrue source={ic_switch_on} />
            : <CheckboxIconFalse source={ic_switch_off} />
          }
        </AnimatedThumb>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}


export default CheckboxToggle;
```

I would like to point out that you are using `useNativeDriver = false`, this may lead to slow animations.

Also, `React-Native` has a `Switch Component`. Why don't you use that?
https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch